# Flash drawing in Actionscript - is it quicker than attachMovie?

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, actionscript-2

I have a Flash application which hold a list of songs. It draws each row individually using Actionscript. Now, when the amount of songs is large, the application crashes on slower machines in the browser with

`A script is causing Adobe Flash Player to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer may become unresponsive. Do you want to abort the script?`

Now I want to know, is it less power/CPU/memory intensive to manually create the row for each song as a `MovieClip` in the library, and instead of drawing the whole row, just use `attachMovie`?

I tried drawing the row once in Actionscript, then tried `duplicateMovieClip` but this doesn't copy the drawing over.

I retreieve the data using `LoadVars` which takes a bit of time depending on the amount of data but that time is of no concern, then I use [Sephiroth Serializer](http://www.sephiroth.it/test/unserializer/) class to unserialize the data, then I begin to draw every row.

Please let me know, appreciate the help.

Comment: adding or duplicating movieclips shouldn't be the reason, perhaps due to the way you populate all the songs... some more info on code would help.

Comment: @loxxy I have updated with a brief description of the code, please do let me know if thats enough information.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `MovieClip` here? While I doubt it will help much, `MovieClip` is not lightweight because it includes timeline functionality. If you have no need for the timeline, **never** use `MovieClip`. Always use a `Sprite`, which `MovieClip` extends and adds the timeline functionality to. **EDIT**: Just realized this is AS2. As Jason Sturges said, AS3 is significantly faster.

Comment: [ActionScript 3 runs significantly faster than legacy ActionScript code](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/actionscript3_overview.html), easily 10x faster.  Without understanding what you "draw each row", blitting copies of the pixel data, assuring no drawing is occurring offstage, use asynchronous patterns or throttle across frames, flatten display list hierarchy, and checking iterative loops would be next steps.

Comment: To me, it seems you have an issue with some type of loop you're using. I would imagine the loop is what's grabbing and placing the content onto your page. I would love to see a snippet of how you're using `duplicateMovieClip()`.

Answer (score 0):

This alert is shown when either there is an infinite loop occurring, or when a given loop takes too long to execute. In 10 years experience with ActionScript, I can't imagine what you could be doing inside a loop that is causing it to run that slowly, so I'm going to guess that your problem is simply that you have an infinite loop running (very easy to do, if you're not careful — we've all been there).

Please post the entirely of the loop code, so that we can answer definitively.